# Combine class and method parameterized type

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface like this:

```
public interface BatchSynchronisedPool<R extends Runnable> {
    void execute(R runnable, Object batchIdentifier);
    public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> callable, Object batchIdentifier);
}
```

I want to infer an upper bound for Callable, but still want to be able to keep the `<T>` argument on the method:

```
public interface BatchSynchronisedPool<R extends Runnable, C extends Callable> {
    void execute(R runnable, Object batchIdentifier);
    public <T> Future<T> submit(C<T> callable, Object batchIdentifier);
}
```

Obviously that doesn't work, because the type of `C` I specify may only take a specific range of `T` arguments.  However, now you have the general just of what I am trying to do, is there a  possible solution, or am I stuck always having to submit a callable? (Or remove generics altogether and perform an unsafe cast)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain, but don't think that you can do what you're trying to do here.  Since `C` is not generic, you can't use `C<T>`.  Lots of code below, but tl;dr **take option 3**.  All that really changes in the end is how many `BatchSynchronisedPool` objects you'll need to create, which is not really a considerable overhead...

---

**1.** Keep the `<T>` generic type parameter on the method, **submit a `Callable<T>` and perform a runtime check of the types**, like your original solution, in the class that implements this interface.

```
public interface BatchSynchronisedPool<R extends Runnable> {
    void execute(R runnable, Object batchIdentifier);
    public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> callable, Object batchIdentifier);
}

public class MyBSP<R, C> implements BatchSynchronisedPool<R, C> {
    void execute(R runnable, Object batchIdentifier) { ... }
    public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> callable, Object batchIdentifier) {
        // Check types.
        if (!(callable instanceof MyDesiredCallableClass)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Types don't match.");
        }

        // Do work.
        T result = callable.call();

        ...
    }
}

public class MyUsageClass {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         // Submit string.
         MyBSP<Runnable> bsp = new MyBSP<Runnable>();
         bsp.submit(new StringCallable(), someObject1);

         // Submit integer.
         bsp.submit(new IntegerCallable(), someObject2);
     }
}
```

---

**2.** Keep the `<T>` generic type parameter on the method, **submit a `C` and perform a cast**, like you've suggested, in the class that implements this interface.

```
public interface BatchSynchronisedPool<R extends Runnable, C extends Callable> {
    void execute(R runnable, Object batchIdentifier);
    public <T> Future<T> submit(Class<T> cls, C callable, Object batchIdentifier);
}

public class MyBSP<R, C> implements BatchSynchronisedPool<R, C> {
    void execute(R runnable, Object batchIdentifier) { ... }
    public <T> Future<T> submit(Class<T> cls, C callable, Object batchIdentifier) {
        // Do work... with a cast.
        T result = cls.cast(callable.call());

        ...
    }
}

public class MyUsageClass {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         // Submit string.
         MyBSP<Runnable, Callable> bsp = new MyBSP<Runnable, Callable>();
         bsp.submit(new StringCallable(), someObject1);

         // Submit integer.
         bsp.submit(new IntegerCallable(), someObject2);
     }
}
```

---

**3. Create a new `BatchSynchronisedPool` for each type `T`** that you're trying to submit by specifying `T` as a generic type parameter for the class.  Then each time you want to call `submit` on a different type, you'd need to generate a new instance of `BatchSynchronisedPool`.

```
public interface BatchSynchronisedPool<T, R extends Runnable, C extends Callable<T>> {
    void execute(R runnable, Object batchIdentifier);
    public Future<T> submit(C callable, Object batchIdentifier);
}

public class MyBSP<T, R, C> implements BatchSynchronisedPool<T, R, C> {
    void execute(R runnable, Object batchIdentifier) { ... }
    public Future<T> submit(C callable, Object batchIdentifier) {
        // Do work.  Types are okay; no checking or casting needed!
        T result = callable.call();

        ...
    }
}

public class MyUsageClass {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         // Submit string.
         MyBSP<String, Runnable, Callable<String>> stringBsp = new MyBSP<String, Runnable, Callable<String>>();
         stringBsp.submit(new StringCallable(), someObject1);

         // Submit integer.
         MyBSP<Integer, Runnable, Callable<Integer>> integerBsp = new MyBSP<Integer, Runnable, Callable<Integer>>();
         integerBsp.submit(new IntegerCallable(), someObject2);
     }
}
```

Comment: If you have the class at runtime as in (2), you can do a checked cast and avoid the warnings at `T result = (T) callable.call()` with `T result = cls.cast(callable.call())`

Comment: Good answer but I see a couple of mistakes in it: in **2.** and **3.** `MyBSP` is not properly implementing the interface as the `submit` method has different signatures. In **2.** the `submit` method in the inteface should have the `Class<T>` parameter. In **3.**, since the class is also parametrized with `T`, I'd remove the `Class<T>` parameter from the class method and I'd move it to a constructor. My 2 cents.

Comment: @AlonsoDominguez You are correct; sorry for those mistakes.  Let it be known that it is a *horrible* idea to edit this much code *in* StackOverflow.  Many, many copy/paste errors.